# java modules: provides... uses don't work in webapp

Tags: java, module

I'm working on a project based on Java modules. I've a parent project (pom project) that contains other modules, a war module and some jar modules.
I want to that a module is a provider, so I've defined a provider class in a module that will be used in an nother module.
During the application startup of the webapplication, defined as following:

```java
@WebListener
public class ServletContext implements ServletContextListener ..
```

I want to get a list of all the services that are provided from a module, so I have used the command:

```java
ServiceLoader<MyClass> services = ServiceLoader.load(MyClass.class);
```

Unfortunately this instruction doesn't retrieve any service.

So, I've made a new project and tried it to understand if I made some mistakes. In the new project, the **ServiceLoader.load**, works properly. In this case I'm not using a servlet to test it but I ran it through a **Main** class.
I'm taken these classeds and put in my original project and tried to run them using a **Main** class, and again the **ServiceLoader.load** works properly.

It seems that the `ServiceLoader.load` doesn't work when I invoke it from the web class, `ServletContext`.

I'm using Java 11, Tomcat 9.0.40.

Is there someone that has already faced this issue?

Answer (score 0):

you can have a file in classpath, just like

```
src
|-- main
    |-- resources
        |-- META-INF
            |-- services
                |-- org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertySource
```

replace `org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertySource` to your own interface name
the content text of the file is class name which implements interface, just like

```
org.apache.logging.log4j.util.EnvironmentPropertySource
```

Comment: you must make sure that the jar is in the directory of  `${java.ext.dirs}`

Comment: I've tried something similar. I'll try it again and I'll let you know

Comment: I've followed your instructions but It still doesn't work. My project is a maven project. When I run it from Eclipse the services list is still empty.